# Реализация асинхронного поиска AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

Кратко логика работы поиска

В мобильном приложении реализован механизм поиска клиентов по Фамилии по точному совпадению(есть серверное API), взято из статьи
[Android AutoCompleteTextView с подсказками из веб-сервиса](https://habr.com/ru/post/243853/)

С той разницей, что в методе поиска Адаптера используется AsyncTask, для получения списка клиентов

```
private List<Client> findClients(String lastName) {
                try {
                    return mGetClients = new GetClients().execute(lastName).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                } catch (ExecutionException e) {

                }
                return null;
            }
```

Все прекрасно работает - после 4 символа, происходит поиск клиентов и на выходе в нижнем выпадающем списке появляется результат, а если к примеру фамилия популярная, то список становится очень большим. 
Вопрос: как реализовать поиск уже внутри данного списка, продолжая вводить через пробел уже имя клиента, тем самым сузить результаты поиска (аналог фильтра при поиске в ListView)

Сделал фильтр адаптера таким образом:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                List<Client> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (constraint != null & !constraint.toString().contains(" ")) {
                    List<Client> clients = findClients(constraint.toString());
                    filterResults.values = clients;
                    filterResults.count = clients.size();
                } else if (constraint != null & constraint.toString().contains(" ")) {
                    String filterPattern = constraint.toString().split(" ")[1].toLowerCase().trim();
                    for (Client clientItem : mGetClients) {
                        if ((clientItem.getDescription().toLowerCase()).contains(filterPattern))
                            filteredList.add(clientItem);
                    }
                    filterResults.values = filteredList;
                    filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            private List<Client> findClients(String clientDesc) {
                try {
                    return mGetClients = new GetClients().execute(clientDesc).get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                } catch (ExecutionException e) {

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    mResults = (List<Client>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: Если реализовано по типу, как в статье, то нужно просто продолжать вводить буквы. Если ваша реализация отличается и после 4 символов фильтрация отключается, то нужно приложить свой код в вопрос.

Comment: После продолжения ввода букв, фильтрация в существующем списке не происходит, т.к. каждый раз происходит вызов AsyncTask(кусок кода приведен выше), который возвращает список клиентов (а если ввести пробел после фамилии, после чего уйдет запрос на сервер с параметром "Иванов "), то соответственно вернется пустой List.

Comment: Если у Вас такой большой список, что все это виснет и долго работает, может тогда просто ограничить кол-во выдаваемых результатов от API? Например не более 10 за раз.

Comment: Так я и так максимально ограничил вывод списка - поиск осуществляется по точному совпадению Фамилии клиента. Тот вариант, который вы предлагаете @beeline09 думаю не подойдет, что если нужный клиент окажется за границей в 10 и вообще слабо представляю с точки зрения UI на клиенте, как это будет выглядеть.
Я уверен, что должно быть решение... Просто в фильтре нужно использовать (после ввода пробела) именно тот список, который получился при поиске по Фамилии (результат метода findClients), а уже дальше фильтровать список List<Client> mGetClients. Например,

Comment: Ну тогда я вижу так. Разделять Через String.split(СИМВОЛ_ПРОБЕЛА) слова вводимые в строке поиска и искать по совпадению в обоих полях. Например ищем Кузнецов Иван. Значит набрали ку, поставили пробел и пишем Иван. На сервере надо искать по полям имя и фамилия, которые содержат Ку или которые содержат Иван, т.е. передавать на сервер все фрагменты, которые мы разделим пробелами.
И второй вариант, если вы загрузили все в адаптер, то с помощью Filterable в адаптере делать то же самое, что на сервере.

Comment: beeline09 Спасибо за наводку! Добавил фильтра адаптера в описание, жду обратной связи от клиентов, в целом работает так как хотелось бы.